# When copying from CSV how I do I had a field like the state the CSV is for?

Tags: postgresql

I know the basic command is `COPY voters FROM '201702_VRDB_Extract.txt' DELIMITER '\t';` What I want to do is add "WA" to the State field for each row of this txt file.

Comment: the easiest would be copying csv to table and then updating the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to pre-process the input file with the state field data.  One simple way to do this is to use `awk` with `OFS` (output field separator) set to `tab` like the following:

```
# Assuming the 5th field of the input file is the state field
awk '{OFS = "\t"; $5 = "WA"; print}' input.txt > inputStateRevised.txt
```

In case you don't have the state field in the existing input file, you can append the state field as follows:

```
# Assuming there are a total of 8 fields in the original input file
awk '{OFS = "\t"; $9 = "WA"; print}' input.txt > inputStateAppended.txt
```